# AttributeError: 'AutoShardedClient' object has no attribute 'add_cog'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a error " *AttributeError: 'AutoShardedClient' object has no attribute 'add_cog'* " when I launch my Discord Bot

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\TRAPPI\TRAPPI.py", line 92, in on_ready
    topgg.setup(client)
  File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\TRAPPI\topgg.py", line 19, in setup
    bot.add_cog(TopGG(bot))
AttributeError: 'AutoShardedClient' object has no attribute 'add_cog'
```

```py
client = discord.AutoShardedClient()
# some code here
@client.event
async def on_ready():
#again and again code
topgg.setup(client)
```

This is in another file

```py
class TopGG(commands.Cog):
#some code here...


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TopGG(bot))
```

Thanks for your help, I'm available if you need more details.

Comment: Probably going to need to see the code along with the traceback

Comment: Late, but you should be using `AutoShardedBot`, not `AutoShardedClient`.